Trying to read data in xml element
I have this XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services/RetrieveFacsimileResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:f1c95072-c1ab-44f4-9c8f-59a26e28fce8</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:0f4a548e-39ad-4b5f-be02-ad9eaae75e32</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ee96d970-c821-455d-9f92-75085fcad001">
            <wsu:Created>2024-06-10T20:27:43Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2024-06-10T20:32:43Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveFacsimileResponse xmlns="http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services">
            <RetrieveFacsimileResult>TestData==</RetrieveFacsimileResult>
        </RetrieveFacsimileResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

I am trying to read the data inside RetrieveFacsimileResult like this:
XmlDocument MyDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
MyDoc.LoadXml(response.Content);
XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("xml/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/RetrieveFacsimileResponse/RetrieveFacsimileResult");

I am getting an error

Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function

How to read the data inside RetrieveFacsimileResult?

Please try the following solution that is using LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.
No need to use a long XPath expression, we are going directly to the XML element of our interest.
Obviously, a default namespace needs to be taken into account.
c#
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'
                   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                   xmlns:wsa='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'
                   xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
                   xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
        <env:Header xmlns:env='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
            <wsa:Action>http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services/RetrieveFacsimileResponse</wsa:Action>
            <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:f1c95072-c1ab-44f4-9c8f-59a26e28fce8</wsa:MessageID>
            <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:0f4a548e-39ad-4b5f-be02-ad9eaae75e32</wsa:RelatesTo>
            <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
            <wsse:Security>
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id='Timestamp-ee96d970-c821-455d-9f92-75085fcad001'>
                    <wsu:Created>2024-06-10T20:27:43Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2024-06-10T20:32:43Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
            </wsse:Security>
        </env:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <RetrieveFacsimileResponse xmlns='http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services'>
                <RetrieveFacsimileResult>TestData==</RetrieveFacsimileResult>
            </RetrieveFacsimileResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>");

    XNamespace ns = "http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services";

    var RetrieveFacsimileResult = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "RetrieveFacsimileResult")?
        .SingleOrDefault()?.Value;
}

Output
TestData==



XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("xml/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/RetrieveFacsimileResponse/RetrieveFacsimileResult");

The initial xml/ is completely spurious - remove it.
The element names RetrieveFacsimileResponse and RetrieveFacsimileResult need to be qualified with a namespace prefix. Choose any prefix you like, and bind it to the namespace http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services.
You can also dive straight in using // rather than giving all the intermediate element names in your path.
Having said that, I agree with @YitzhakKabinsky that for a very simple query like this, using LINQ method directly makes more sense than using XPath expressions.
